# Duplicar Registros em Massa - Rodar uma query pra cada Registro exibido

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, sql-select

Tenho uma Tabela onde somente é exibido as contas com seu tipo='fixa'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu gostaria de realizar é rodar uma consulta e duplicar todos os Registros da tabela de uma vez só. No momento consegui apenas realizar a duplicação das contas uma por uma e não todos os resultados exibidos, o que já ajuda mas não resolve meu problema hehehe.

**estou rodando a seguinte consulta:**

$tSqlDup = $tPdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Contas (Data_Vencimento, Nome, Cedente, Centro_Custo, Finalidade, Valor)SELECT Data_Vencimento, Nome, Cedente, Centro_Custo, Finalidade, Valor FROM tab_contas WHERE ID = '{$tGet}'");

$tSqlDup ->execute();

A ideia disto é retirar o trabalho do usuário ficar relançando contas que terão dados exatamente iguais, talvez diferenciando vencimento e valor... e ao clicar no botão todos valores do tipo fixo serem duplicados...

vou deixar abaixo toda a estrutura HTML abaixo:

```html
<table class="table">
    
 <thead>
        
    <tr style="background-color: #428bca;">
                        
        <th>Vencimento</th>

        <th>Nome da Conta</th>

        <th>Cedente</th>

        <th>Finalidade</th>

        <th>CC</th>

        <th>Valor da Ultima Conta</th>

        <th>Duplicar</th>

    </tr>

</thead>
      
<tbody>

<?php
 
require_once("includes/BaseDeDados.php");
require_once("includes/LogSistema.php");
           
    $tQuantidade = 100;
    $tPagina     = (isset ($_GET['pg'])) ? (int)$_GET['pg'] :1;
    $tIniciar    = ($tQuantidade * $tPagina) - $tQuantidade;

    $tSql = $tPdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contas WHERE Tipo='F' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $tIniciar, $tQuantidade");
$tSql ->execute();
      
      while($tMC  = $tSql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {   

      //Faz o explode da Data para transformar data do formato US para o formato BR
      $data = $tMC['Data_Vencimento'];
      $data_nova = explode("-",$data);
      // Calcula Mês atual + 1
      $mes = strtotime("+1 month");

      echo "
        <tr>
            
          <td>$data_nova[2]/".date('m', $mes)."/$data_nova[0]</td>

          <td><a href='?controle=***ARQUIVO***&CodC=".codificarUrl($tMC['ID'])."' rel='tooltip' title='Editar Esta Conta'>".utf8_encode($tMC['Nome'])."</td>

          <td>{$tMC['Cedente']}</td>

          <td>{$tMC['Finalidade']}</td>

          <td>{$tMC['Centro_Custo']}</td>

          <td>R$ {$tMC['Valor']}</td>
          
<!--- ////////////////////////////
ESTE E O BOTAO QUE RODA A CONSULTA PARA DUPLICAR A CONTA COM O ID ESCOLHIDO, POREM GOSTARIA DE AO INVES TER DE FAZER ISTO DE CONTA EM CONTA, REALIZAR EM TODAS DE UMA VEZ...
/////////////////////////////////-->
          <td><a href='?controle=***ARQUIVO***&Acao=Duplicar&CodC=".codificarUrl($tMC["ID"])."' role='button' rel='tooltip' title='Duplicar este Arquivo'></a></td>
          
        </tr>";

      }
        
  if (isset($_GET['Acao']) && isset($_GET['CodC']))
    {

# É AQUI AONDE É RODADA A CONSULTA QUE FAZ A DUPLICAÇÃO DA CONTA

      $tGet    = decodificarUrl($_GET['CodC']);
      $tSqlDup = $tPdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Contas (Data_Vencimento, Nome, Cedente, Centro_Custo, Finalidade, Valor) SELECT Data_Vencimento, Nome, Cedente, Centro_Custo, Finalidade, Valor FROM tab_contas WHERE ID = '{$tGet}'");
     
      $tSqlDup ->execute();       
    
    }

?>

<tbody>
    
</table>
```

PS: Na SS tem os botões a direita da tabela, e o botão acima da tabela, o acima da tabela não funciona, seria o botão que duplicaria tudo de uma vez só, enquanto os botões a direita de cada Conta são os botões que duplicam uma de cada vez...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode continuar utilizando sua query que faz um insert por vez, apenas colocando ela dentro de um loop que passe por todos os itens.

```
$query_itens = $tPdo->prepare("SELECT ID FROM tab_contas WHERE SUA_CONDICAO_AQUI")->execute();
$itens = $query_itens->fetchAll();

$tSqlDup = $tPdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Contas (Data_Vencimento, Nome, Cedente, Centro_Custo, Finalidade, Valor)SELECT Data_Vencimento, Nome, Cedente, Centro_Custo, Finalidade, Valor FROM tab_contas WHERE ID = ?");

foreach($itens as $item) {
    $tSqlDup->execute([$item->id]);
}
```

Apenas altere a condição da primeira query para corresponder ao seu caso.

Comment: `prepare` -> `execute` ?

Comment: ao adicionar o [$item->id] dentro do execute "$tSqlDup->execute([$item->id]);" está dando erro

Comment: @BenhurDaSilveiraKulzer Qual erro?

Comment: @Edilson É a mesma coisa que fazer `$a = $pdo->prepare(); $a->execute()`

Comment: Digo, o `execute` só aceita array.

Comment: @Edilson Não entendi.